# Is it possible to have single stable dagre layout in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

cytoscape.js dagre layout works really well.

However there is no single stable layout given particular graph.
The layout algorithm seems to be using some random number generator to calculate node positions. It leads to annoying situation when the same graph sometimes rendered differently on the screen.

Is any simple way to fix that? Usually random seed value could be set to some user-defined number. I was unable to find suggestion on how to do that in cytoscape.js docs.

Comment: Are you sure that the graph algo uses random numbers? The [example](https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape.js-dagre) for the dagre layout seems to be the same everytime. Maybe your graph isn't exactly a DAG? Can you show us the nodes please? :) Thanks

Comment: Cytoscape always uses the elements in the layout in the order that they exist in the passed collection (usually the full set of elements, in order of addition to the graph).  It may be that Dagre itself has some randomisation, but I doubt it.  It may be that the order of your elements is not consistent between layout calls?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar issue with Dagre as well. After digging a little bit into the source code, the reason might be with the ranking algorithm that's used:

[Link](https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre/blob/76058e545939b4381f4e5f748f6f2f800a803479/lib/rank/index.js#L46)

AFAIK, network simplex algorithm chooses a random starting to find the optimum, and in case where multiple optima exist, it doesn't guarantee that the same solution will be reached every time.